# Native module cannot be null: IOS 0.57

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am using Razorpay and have set up everything followed Razorpay docs
but the thing is when I build the IOS app then I have got " Native module cannot be null". but some times it's working good. I don't know why this error I am getting. Can anyone help me out

Comment: Please make sure that Razorpay.framework is present in the embedded libraries section of your build settings and libRazorpay.a should be there in linked libraries.

Comment: did you add the following, $(PROJECT_DIR)/../node_modules/react-native-razorpay/ios/, under framework search paths? and when you mentioned that it has worked before, have you tried rolling back to that particular commit to test and see what went wrong?